# In need to create a java program that uses a loop to check if a password is correct. The program runs but the output isn't correct

Tags: java, loops

Any time I enter a password whether it is in valid format or invalid format, it always outputs "Invalid password".

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
    public class PasswordTest
    {
       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          boolean length = true;
          boolean digit = true;
          boolean lowercase = true;
          boolean uppercase = true;
          char ch = 0;
          String s1;

       //Prompt user to enter password
          System.out.print("Enter password: ");
          s1 = input.nextLine();

       //Check what ch is
          for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
             ch = s1.charAt(i);

             if (Character.isDigit(ch)){
                digit = true;
             }
             if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
                lowercase = true;
             }    
             if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                uppercase = true;
             }
             if (s1.length()>=8){
                length = true;
             }
          }

          if (digit==false && lowercase==false && uppercase==false && length==false)
             System.out.println("Valid password");

          else
             System.out.println("Invalid password");

       }
    }
```

Comment: How could any of your booleans turn out `false` when you never assign a value different to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first set all the boolean values to `false` at the time of declaration, and then in the code below set it to `true` only if it satisfies the condition. Also while printing "Valid Password" check if all boolean values are `true`, else print "Invalid Password". Checking if string length is greater than 8 should be outside the loop body. Following code works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PasswordTest
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean length = false;
      boolean digit = false;
      boolean lowercase = false;
      boolean uppercase = false;
      char ch=0;
      String s1;

   //Prompt user to enter password
      System.out.print("Enter password: ");
      s1 = input.nextLine();

   //Check what ch is
      for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
         ch = s1.charAt(i);

         if (Character.isDigit(ch)){
            digit = true;
         }
         if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
            lowercase = true;
         }    
         if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
            uppercase = true;
         }             
      }
      if (s1.length()>=8){
          length = true;
       }

      if (digit==true && lowercase==true && uppercase==true && length==true)
         System.out.println("Valid password");

      else
         System.out.println("Invalid password");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a question for you, if it can't it be lowercase and if it cant be uppercase then what could it be? I made it so it has to be lowercase, here is the code (if you want it to be all uppercase then change this if statement in the code `if(digit[i] == true || lowercase[i] == false || uppercase[i] == true)` to `if(digit[i] == true || lowercase[i] == true || uppercase[i] == false)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordTest{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean length;
        boolean pass = true;
        String s1;

       //Prompt user to enter password
        System.out.print("Enter password: ");
        s1 = input.nextLine();
        boolean[] digit = new boolean[s1.length()];
        boolean[] lowercase = new boolean[s1.length()];
        boolean[] uppercase = new boolean[s1.length()];
        char[] ch = new char[s1.length()];
       //Check what ch is
        for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
            ch[i] = s1.charAt(i);
            digit[i] = Character.isDigit(ch[i]);
            lowercase[i] = Character.isLowerCase(ch[i]);
            uppercase[i] = Character.isUpperCase(ch[i]);

          }
        length = s1.length()>=8;
        if (length==false && s1.length() > 0) {
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < s1.length(); i ++){
                if(digit[i] == true|| lowercase[i] == false|| uppercase[i] == true)
                    pass = false;
            }
            if(pass == true)
                System.out.println("Valid password");
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid password");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid password");
        }

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is first set the boolean value to true then again in loop you are setting it to true which doesnot makes sense.I think this code will work fine for you

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean length = false;
        boolean digit = false;
        boolean lowercase = false;
        boolean uppercase = false;
        char ch = '\u0000';
        String s1;

        //Prompt user to enter password
        System.out.print("Enter password: ");
        s1 = input.nextLine();

        //Check what ch is
        for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
            ch = s1.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(ch)){
                digit = true;
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
                lowercase = true;
            }
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                uppercase = true;
            }
            if (s1.length()>=8){
                length = true;
            }
        }

        if (digit==true && lowercase==true && uppercase==true && length==true)
            System.out.println("Valid password");

        else
            System.out.println("Invalid password");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future, I think [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) would be helpful.

Your password requirements seem to be "8 or more characters in length, where each character may be a lowercase letter, a capital letter, or a digit," is that right? We can express those requirements with a regular expression, such as `([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){8,}`. With this, we may write

```
String password = input.nextLine();

if(password.matches("([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){8,}") {
    // Go about your business.
}
```

Comment: ```00000000``` matches that.